# Error al descargar el servicio Web SiiFactFEV1SOAP de la AEAT

Tags: visual-studio, webservice, aeat-sii

Intento añadir a un proyecto nuevo en Visual Studio 2017 una referencia al servicio Web de Suministro Inmediato de Información (SII) de la Agencia Tributaria Española (AEAT) con la Url de entorno de pruebas.

Desde el explorador de soluciones, selecciono el proyecto, menu contextual añadir referencia de servicio, dirección "https://www7.aeat.es/wlpl/SSII-FACT/ws/fe/SiiFactFEV1SOAP"

Responde el siguiente error:

> There was an error downloading 'https://www7.aeat.es/wlpl/SSII-FACT/ws/fe/SiiFactFEV1SOAP/$metadata'.

Si pruebo con las opciones avanzadas, añadir referencia web, me solicita el certificado de la FNMT, acepto, y me devuelve el mismo error.

¿Hay algo que se me escapa?

Answer (score 2):

Estaba tomando como url del servicio la dirección del EndPoint.

La url correcta (para la versión V.06 en pruebas) del servicio web es la siguiente:

http://www.agenciatributaria.es/static_files/AEAT/Contenidos_Comunes/La_Agencia_Tributaria/Modelos_y_formularios/Suministro_inmediato_informacion/FicherosSuministros/V_06/SuministroFactEmitidas.wsdl

Comment: ¡Bien que lo has visto! Yo en mi caso lo he usado con el SoapClient de PHP sin tener que importar servicio/generar clases sino simplemente crear un array asociativo multidimensional de PHP que luego al pasarlo como parámetro en la llamada, lo codifica de forma automática al XML que necesita. Si alguien quiere ver en PHP todo el circuito puede echar un vistazo al ebook de http://www.aeatsiidesarrolladores.es/